# Metadata error when upgrading an MVC4 App fom .net 4.0 to 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I was asked recently to upgrade an MVC4 web app from .net4.0 to .net4.5 so I just changed target framework to .net framework 4.5 (it should do the job). This web app contains an entity framework database model .edmx.
No compiling errors was found but when trying to launch the web app I got this error:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzGz0.png][1]

This is the error message (in text format)

---

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>
> error 0194: All artifacts loaded into an ItemCollection must have the same version. Multiple versions were encountered.
>
> error 0194: All artifacts loaded into an ItemCollection must have the same version. Multiple versions were encountered.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>
> error 0194: All artifacts loaded into an ItemCollection must have the same version. Multiple versions were encountered.
>
> error 0194: All artifacts loaded into an ItemCollection must have the same version. Multiple versions were encountered.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 41:         /// Initialize a new RemediationModelContainer object.
>
> Line 42:         ///
>
> Line 43:         public RemediationModelContainer(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "RemediationModelContainer")
>
> Line 44:         {
>
> Line 45:             this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

Anyone has an idea why I got this error and how to fix it.

---

This is the runtime section of the web.config file

```
  <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

</dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
         -->
            
                
                
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
         -->

Comment: The error message is far more useful and searchable as text than as an image link.

Comment: Submit your `web.config` as well.

Comment: What section do you want ?

Comment: I just updated the question with the runtime section of the web.config